# Is this considered a tail call?

Tags: c++

I know that a recursive tail call is when a function calls itself as its last action.  Would the following be considered a tail call even when the function call isn't in the last line.

```
void test(int a)
{
    if(a == 1)
       return;
    else if(a % 2 == 0)
       test(a / 2);
    else
       test(3 * a - 1);
}
```

Say a were an even number.  Would calling test(a/2) be considered a tail call?

Comment: The calls to `test` occur at a [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) position. Basically any function that is invoked as the *last action* - this means the return value must be discarded or immediately returned [but of course these don't apply to `void`] - is in a tail call position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, not that it means much in C++. Tail call elimination isn't required by C++; compilers can do it sometimes, but they quite often won't. You can't rely on it like you would in Scheme.

Comment: But if a compiler does tail call elimination, it should do so for this function.

Comment: @Barmar: That's a bit strong. It would not be unreasonable for a tail call optimizer to work only on functions that have one branch and one tail call. The problem is that recognizing the opportunity for TCO requires flow analysis, which in general has exponential complexity.